# Replace None with NaN and ignore NoneType in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm attempting to create a raw string variable from a pandas dataframe, which will eventually be written to a *.cfg* file, by firstly joining two columns together as shown below and avoiding `None`:

Section of `df`:

```
                         command                          value
...
439                      sensitivity                      "0.9"
440        cl_teamid_overhead_always                          1
441                 host_writeconfig                       None
...
```

`code`:

```
...
df = df['value'].replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
print df
df = df['command'].astype(str)+' '+df['value'].astype(str)
print df
cfg_output = '\n'.join(df.tolist())
print cfg_output
```

I've attempted to replace all the `None` values with `NaN` firstly so that ***no*** lines in `cfg_output` contain "None" as part of of the string. However, by doing so I seem to get a few undesired results. I made use of print statements to see what is going on.

It seems that `df = df['value'].replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)`, simply outputs `None`.

It seems that `df = df['command'].astype(str)+' '+df['value'].astype(str)` and `cfg_output = '\n'.join(df.tolist())`, cause the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Therefore, I was thinking that by ignoring any occurrences of NaN, the code may run smoothly, although I'm unsure about how to do so using `Pandas`

Ultimately, my ***desired output*** would be as followed:

```
sensitivity "0.9"
cl_teamid_overhead_always 1
host_writeconfig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `df['value'].replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)` returns `None` because you're calling the method with the `inplace=True` argument. This argument tells `replace` to not return anything but instead modify the original `dataframe` as it is. Similar to how `pop` or `append` work on lists.

With that being said, you can also get the desired output calling `fillna` with an empty string:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {
    'command': ['sensitivity', 'cl_teamid_overhead_always', 'host_writeconfig'],
    'value': ['0.9', 1, None]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
# df['value'].replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
df = df['command'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['value'].fillna('').astype(str)
cfg_output = '\n'.join(df.tolist())

>>> print(cfg_output)

sensitivity 0.9
cl_teamid_overhead_always 1
host_writeconfig
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can `replace` None to ''

```
df=df.replace('None','')
df['command'].astype(str)+' '+df['value'].astype(str)
Out[436]: 
439                sensitivity 0.9
440    cl_teamid_overhead_always 1
441              host_writeconfig 
dtype: object
```